# Different target names using Rust Cargo for build

Tags: build, rust, rust-cargo

Is there a way to set different target names for development and release configurations using Cargo for building? For example, rustlibd.a and rustlib.a?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Debug vs release information is controlled by a *profile*. You can see [all the profile-related manifest keys in the source code](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/blob/5b0bf5459d296c3e49b22d66c5a3870d42597d25/src/cargo/core/manifest.rs#L154-L179). The only related one I see is `rustc_options`. Running the build in verbose mode, you can see how cargo calls rustc:

```
$ cargo build --verbose
   Compiling namez v0.1.0 (file:///private/tmp/namez)
     Running `rustc --crate-name namez src/lib.rs --crate-type lib --emit=dep-info,link -C debuginfo=2 -C metadata=5444c772a04e08f3 -C extra-filename=-5444c772a04e08f3 --out-dir /private/tmp/namez/target/debug/deps -L dependency=/private/tmp/namez/target/debug/deps`
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.45 secs
```

Unfortunately, changing `--crate-name` does not have the effect you'd like.

---

Instead, I'd point out that you *already* have a different filename, you just have to look broader:

```
target/debug/libname.a
target/release/libname.a
```

The debug and release files are in **different** directories. Whatever you were going to do to move separately named libraries would have to deal with the `debug` and `release` directories *anyway*. Just update your script:

```
mv target/debug/libname.a libnamed.a
mv target/release/libname.a libname.a
```

Comment: Ok, thank you. I hoped that there's enough to use just Cargo. But I also have known that Cargo cannot perform post-build script so in this situation external build tool should be used.